# Is it possible to restrict the Terms shown in the MetadataNavigationHierarchy?

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, taxonomy, term-store

I have the following scenario:

- A Term Set setup called "Projects"
- The first level of terms under "Projects" are all names of Clients (eg. ClientA, ClientB, ClientC...)
- The second level of terms under each Client are names of actual Projects (eg. ClientA\ProjectX, ClientA\ProjectY, ClientB\ProjectZ...)
- A root level site collection that house a collection of Client subsites.
- Each client subsite contains a document library that has a column linked to the "Projects" term set.

I have the following requirement to implement:

- When browsing a document library within the site for ClientA (url: http://root/ClientA) the metadata navigation hierarchy should only display the second level of terms that are underneath "ClientA" in the Term Set (eg. ProjectX, ProjectY).

Any ideas on what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. wherein the termset will be categorized according to the department and the term for one department should not be visible for the other department, the termset will be configured in the document library. would like to know how you achieved this. With regards
srividya S

Comment: @srividya it is possible using the UI as Neil mentioned below and it is logical that it *should* be possible to implmement in code. As my comment below though i did not end up implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

I would customise the "Project" site column. Instead of looking at the 1st level (Client Name) I would start it at the 2nd level (Project name) and then within each site/library ensure that column is configured against the correct Client. This can be done either via the UI or via code (in case you have an event handler that fires when creating a site/list).

Cheers

Neil

Comment: Thanks Neil, looks like it works via the UI, unfortunately i now have a conflicting requirement so currently won't be able to look into implementing this in code :(